# substitution integration question

Tags: integration

I want to integrate $\int \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx $.

When I substitute $x = \sin θ$ , I get the right answer. ( $ \cos^2\theta$ before integration)

But when I substitute $x = \cos θ$ , I don't get the right answer. ( $ -\sin^2\theta$ before integration).

What step is wrong here? If I proceed like this, don't I end up with a wrong answer?

Comment: I get the same result with both substitutions. Can you show us your work so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: @5xum I'm guessing he/she's having trouble with the derivative of $\cos(\theta)$ having a negative term, and the  $\sin(\theta)$ doesn't.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Possibly. But unless he shows his work, we cannot really help him.

Comment: When I substitute x = sinθ, the equivalent integration function becomes cosθ (cos^2 θ)^0.5. The other substitution yields -sinθ (sin^2 θ)^0.5. Am I wrong in this step?

Comment: @Igj No you are not; proceed with the integral and tell us where you go wrong.

Comment: see what happens when you evaluate a definite integral using the same substitutions, say $\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$

Comment: Ok, let's say I use the limits of 0 to 1/(2)^0.5 for the x function. The corresponding limits for the θ function will be 0 to pi/4 for both substitutions. Using a calculator, I get 0.643 for cosθ(cos^2 θ)^0.5. The other substitution  -sinθ(sin^2 θ)^0.5 yields -0.143.

Comment: Okay, mistake found, the limits for substitution x=cosθ are wrong. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Hint: $ \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}= |\cos \theta| \ne \cos \theta$. and the same for $ \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}= |\sin \theta| \ne \sin \theta$, so the integration requaire a bit more attention.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is they become the same answer once you back-substitute $\theta$ for $x$.

It makes more sense if you actually do the integrals.

$$\begin{align} \int \cos^2 \theta \,d\theta &= \frac{1}{2}\int (1 +\cos 2\theta)\,d\theta \\&= \frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{4}\sin 2\theta + C \\&= \frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta + C \\&= \frac{1}{2}\arcsin x + \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2} + C \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} \int -\sin^2 \theta \,d\theta &= -\frac{1}{2}\int (1 -\cos 2\theta)\,d\theta \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{4}\sin 2\theta + C \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta + C \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\arccos x + \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2} + C \end{align}$$

The key here is that $\arcsin x$ and $-\arccos x$ differ by a constant

$$\arcsin x + C_1 = -\arccos x + \frac{\pi}{2} + C_1 = -\arccos x + C_2$$

What this means is when you take the derivative, the constant goes away, leaving the same function, so the 2 answers you get are equivalent.